# How to set relative directory to PATH variable, and run scripts in relative directory globally

Tags: bash, path

I have some some scripts in a git project I wan to access globally, so I add the relative path to the scripts folder like so

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="~/git/scripts/:$PATH"
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and there is a file `~/git/scripts/` called `echoHelloWorld.sh`, so how I can I run `echoHelloWorld.sh` if I am for example in the `~/Downloads` folder? Do I do

```
cd ~/Downloads
./echoHelloWorld
```

because I have tried that, but it does not work, and I have also tried `chmod +x echoHelloWorld.sh` with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Your path statement in `~/.bash_profile` should look like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/git/scripts/
```

#### The basics.....

There are three problems with the way you wrote it:

- Shouldn't use the `export` function since the variable (`PATH`) is already in the environment.  When you logged in, the `PATH` variable was created and set.  You don't need to `export` it as it already exists.
- Remove the double quotes.  Double quotes cause the path to be read literally so the `~` home directory expansion never takes place.  For tilde expansion to work, it can't be enclosed in quotes.  If you want to verify this, at the command line type the following:

  ```
  $ PATH="~/git/scripts:$PATH"
  $ echo $PATH
  ~/git/scripts:/opt/local/bin:...                  <====== INCORRECT RESULT

  $ PATH=~/git/scripts:$PATH
  $ echo $PATH
   /Users/foouser/git/scripts:/opt/local/bin:.....  <====== CORRECT!
  ```
- Your tilde expanded (personal home directory) paths should be at the *end* of your path statement.  Your path is read from left to right, taking precedence as it goes.  In other words, if there is a command/function in your home directory with the same name as something already in your `PATH` it will be executed (found) first and may have unintended consequences.

Once you make the change to your `~/.bash_profile` you can restart your session or just source it as you did before and the changes will take place.  You can confirm that it worked by issing either (or both) the following commands:

```
$ echo $PATH
$ which echoHelloWorld.sh
```

The first will output the `PATH` as set and the second will tell you where in the path it found your script.

Comment: While I agree with you that `~/git/scripts:$PATH` is incorrect, `bash` will perform tilde expansion within each PATH component, unlike other shells. In this case, `export PATH="~/git/scripts/:$PATH"` , the tilde is not a relative path.

Comment: @fd0 - it won't expand it if you put it in quotes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but actually the component `~/git/scripts` does in `bash`.

Comment: @fd0 - then I'm confused by your comment because I explain that in my bullet second point.

Comment: Your second bullet point reads that neither tilde expansion nor parameter expansion work if the assignment is quoted. You might fix that.

Comment: @fd0 - is it clearer?

Comment: What @fd0 is saying is something else: In `bash`, `~/git/scripts` is a valid component of `PATH` which will get searched as expected (aka the `~` gets expanded during search). See https://gist.github.com/nohillside/b1eb0d5b0718b77384fb0daefc04dbff

Comment: @nohillside - I'm not saying it isn't.  I'm saying the double quotes are causing the problem.

Comment: No, the fact that the OP types different name, combined with calling it with `./` cause the problem. A `~` in `PATH` is not the problem, the OP would be happy if they just typed the correct name without the `./` in front.

Comment: You say "For tilde expansion to work, it can't be enclosed in quotes.". This is *not true* for `bash`, tilde expansion *does* occur (just not during assignment).

Comment: @Allan Thanks, the double quotes were the problem. You said I don't need to export `PATH` because it's already exported. If I export my `JAVA_HOME` in `bash_profile` like this `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` do I still need to include `JAVA_HOME` in the path variable like so `PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}` in `bash_profile` or is there no point, now that both `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` are exported?

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't need to export variables that are already created in the environment.  `PATH` already exists, `JAVA_HOME` doesn't.  What you're doing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the path of the file to run to your `PATH` variable you can run your command directly with

```
 echoHelloWorld.sh
```

independent of the directory you are in. Running it as `./echoHelloWorld.sh` actually explicitly tells the shell to ignore `PATH` and run the script from the current directory (where it is not available).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make your command executable.

   ```
   chmod +x echoHelloWorld.sh 
   # verify it worked.
   ls -l echoHelloWorld.sh
   ```
2. edit your profile, which most often is ~/.bash_profile Add the directory to your path variable.

   ```
   # some people recommend putting your scripts at the end of path. 
   # Less risk of you accidentally overriding a system file name.
   PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/git/scripts/"
   ```
3. I'd quit the session.  You don't know if your profile script will like to be run twice.
4. start a new session
5. run by

   ```
   echoHelloWorld.sh
   ```

Here is my example:

```
$ oneApp
-bash: oneApp: command not found
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Developer/Tools:/Users/mac/.nexustools
$ export PATH="~/oneFile:$PATH"
$ echo $PATH
~/oneFile:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Developer/Tools:/Users/mac/.nexustools
$ oneApp
Running oneApp
$ cat oneApp
cat: oneApp: No such file or directory
$ cat ~/oneFile/oneApp 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running oneApp"
$
```

Comment: Which file does the OP need to edit in step 2?